# What is the Z3 option hi_div0?

Tags: z3

What does the Z3 option `hi_div0` mean? I was unable to find any documentation.

How does that option affect performance and how does it affect semantics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hi_div0` stands for "Hardware Interpretation of Division by zero. When enabled, this means that divison by zero has a concrete value instead of being uninterpreted (and the remainder too). See e.g., [bv_rewriter](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/unstable/src/ast/rewriter/bv_rewriter.cpp#L700), which defines the values for signed division; the other values are further down in the same file.

Comment: Does it affect performance? I read that it disables something about the SAT solver.

Comment: Yes, if it's disabled, the solver needs to be able to reason about uninterpreted functions as well, so it uses a different solver. This can be faster, but usually it will be slower.